# How to program a 'biweekly event' in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date

I have a system where a user can choose for a certain event to trigger weekly, biweekly or monthly.

Now, weekly and monthly are easy -- I have a cron job running every day, and if someone sets the setting as 'weekly' I simply check if the day is monday. If it's monthly, I check if the day of the month is 1.

But biweekly is a little bit more tricky. My first thought was to check if it's monday, and then to check if it's been an even number of weeks since the start of the year. I'm not 100% certain on this, but I do feel confident that there's a possibility, when the year switches over, that you could have 2 weeks in a row where it triggers, or two weeks in a row where it doesn't trigger.

My other idea which potentially gets over this is to check if it's been an even number of weeks since a particular date in the past -- say, since Jan 1 2020.

Both of those logic, in my mind, would involve using Carbon to get the `->diffInDays()`, divide that by 7, floor the result, and check if the result is even or odd. I just wanted to check if any of these ideas are a good way to implement 'biweekly' or if I need to think of something else.

Comment: By `biweekly` are you meaning twice a week or every two weeks?

Comment: once every two weeks

Answer (score 0):

I think your second idea is ok. I use as date in the past the 1 january 1970.

You don't need Carbon. The native DateTime works fine.

```
$strDate = 'today';
//$strDate = '2020-05-04';  //for test
//$strDate = '2020-05-11';  //for test

$curDate = date_create($strDate);
$biweekly = ((int)(date_create('@0')->diff($curDate)->days/7))%2;
//result is 0 or 1

$start = ($biweekly AND $curDate->format('w') == 1); //true for every 2nd Monday
```

If you want to use the other week then do:

```
$start = ($biweekly == 0 AND $curDate->format('w') == 1);
```

Another variant takes a specific date with the desired weekday as the start date.
There is a 2 week cycle if the difference between days from the start date to the current day is divisible by 14 without a rest.

```
$startDate = '2020-05-04';  //a monday
$ev14Days = date_create($startDate)->diff(date_create('today'))->days%14 == 0;
//true on 2020-05-18, 2020-06-01, ..
```